# Jstree checkbox, get only the children id

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have a tree of 5 levels, but only the children have a custom id.

```
<div id="jstree-naf">
    <ul>
        {% for key, naf in json["naf"] %}
        <li>{{ key }}
            <ul>
            {% for key2, naf2 in naf %}
                <li>{{ key2 }}
                    <ul>
                    {% for key3, naf3 in naf2 %}
                        <li>{{ key3 }}
                            <ul>
                            {% for key4, naf4 in naf3 %}
                                <li>{{ key4 }}
                                    <ul>
                                    {% for key5, naf5 in naf4 %}
                                        <li id="{{ key5 }}">{{ naf5 }}</li>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

But when I select something, I got the id of the children, but also the automatic id of the parents.

```
 ["58.11Z", "j2_1212"]
```

My id is "58.11Z", but "j2_1212" is the one of his direct parent, created automatically by jstree, but I don't need it.

Here is my basic initialisation:

```
$('#jstree-naf').jstree({
    "plugins" : [ "wholerow", "checkbox" ]
});

$('#jstree-naf').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
    console.log(data.selected);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your checkbox plugin according to your requirements here.
See here [jsTree Checkbox plugin config options](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=$.jstree.defaults.checkbox&f=$.jstree.defaults.checkbox.cascade).

For your requirements you need to set **`$.jstree.defaults.checkbox.three_state`** to **false**(as it defaults to true) and **`$.jstree.defaults.checkbox.cascade`** to **up/down/undetermined**.

As mentioned in the jstree site for '$.jstree.defaults.checkbox.cascade'

> This setting controls how cascading and undetermined nodes are 
>   applied.
>
> If 'up' is in the string - cascading up is enabled,
>
> if 'down'  is in the string - cascading down is enabled,
>
> if 'undetermined' is in  the string - undetermined nodes will be
>   used.
>
> If three_state is set to  true this setting is automatically set to
>   'up+down+undetermined'.  Defaults to ''

In your case you don't want cascading up to be enabled, you can set cascade option to '**down+undetermined**'

To keep cascading up to be enabled and still get only selected child elements.
use [get_bottom_selected](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=get_bottom_selected([full])) method.

```
$('#jstree-naf').jstree().get_bottom_selected()
```

Comment: I want the cascading (so I want all the children (the lowest level)), but I don't need the parents id

Comment: for that use [get_bottom_selected](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=get_bottom_selected([full])) method.  This will return selected nodes except their parents

Comment: Thanks @Chetan, but how does it work ? console.log(data.get_bottom_selected); returns undefined :/

Comment: Go through that documentation link. It's a method , not a property. data.get_bottom_selected() will return array of IDs. To get full node object, pass boolean parameter as true.

Comment: data.get_bottom_selected() returns TypeError: data.get_bottom_selected is not a function

Comment: $('#jstree-naf').jstree().get_bottom_selected()

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I need, thanks @Chetan (edit your answer with this)

Answer (score 0):

Does it always return the selected node as the first item, and then parent nodes afterwards? If so, you could just take the first item:

```
$('#jstree-naf').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
    console.log(data.selected[0]);
});
```